# To what extent do performers "hear" sheet music?

Tags: notation, ear-training

Sheet music enables instrumental performers who are able to read music notation (a pianist, orchestral instrument players, a jazz band, etc.) or singers to perform a song or piece.

Presumably some performers are able to "hear" sheet music from reading prior to performance.  Particularly music for a single (known) instrument, such as Beethoven's [moonlight sonata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_(Beethoven)).

To what extent do such people "hear" sheet music?

Can notated music be largely judged (by some) from the page, without literally hearing it?

EDIT - By judge I just meant the same way I would "judge" music upon listening.  As in decide whether it is good or bad or worth listening to again, etc.  And how similar it can elicit some emotional reaction, whether good or bad.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example of "judging" music you have in mind?

Comment: I've edited to hopefully explain what I mean.

Comment: If it's helpful in finding literature, the term for this is "audiation."

Comment: Beethoven wrote about a third of his compositions after he became totally deaf.

Comment: I'm going to trot out my anecdote of the friend whilst holding the score and listening to a poor choir perform a brand new piece, went outside with the comment "I can either read this or listen to them. I can't do both at once."

Comment: The edit puts a lot of subjectivity into the question. I guess to be able to decide if it's 'good or bad', one must essentially be able to sight-read it internally at least, anyhow. And that's not a rare talent amongst musicians.

Comment: @Tim yeah I realised that after waking up today.  It's maybe not possible to answer generally I suppose.  From the thread posted in one answer, it seems to be able to "hear" it off the page to the extent that you don't need to literally hear it, is quite a rare ability.

Comment: In my opinion this question is opinion based and there has never been a serious study except of the training of music conservatories and music schools which neglect these abilities in favor of virtuosity  and instrumental technique.

Comment: The answer is yes. But are you interested in developing that skill yourself?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis  Not really.  I think I'm too old anyway (even if I possessed the requisite skills), and notated music would say little about a lot of music I listen to.  I was just fascinated that someone could have a similar reaction to reading (certain) music notated that I would have listening.

Comment: I read endless amounts of organ sheet music to decide what I'm going to play next Sunday. It's almost always easy to decide whether something is competently enough written to be presentable; judging the artistic value is more iffy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Training to be a singer includes what is called "ear training" which is the act of hearing the pitch in your "ear" (mind, really) before you phonate (sing) it. This ability keeps you in tune while you sing.

You also learn how to read music and, eventually, you learn how to "sight-read" it. This means you can pick up sheet music and sing the notes without ever having heard them before.

So, I can tell you that singers who can "sight-read" music do hear the pitch in their "ear" before they phonate it. In fact, being able to sight-reading music they've never seen before is a required skill for any singer wanting to perform in a choir.

Comment: The thing is, people who don't have absolute pitch apparently *do* need that initial instrumental intro/piano chord/etc. before they can truly sing the music in its correct key, which means that either they can hear the pitch in their mind's ear but are somehow unable to pitch-match it or they in fact cannot hear the pitch in their mind's ear, which contradicts your statement that "So, I can tell you that singers who can "sight-read" music do hear the pitch in their "ear" before they phonate it". (I personally don't have the greatest clue how sight-singing doesn't translate to absolute pitch.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci - Most of us (not just musicians) have a sort of absolute pitch.  That is, if we play a popular tune in our heads, most of us usually hear it in the correct key.  The term absolute pitch is usually reserved for people who can identify pitch outside of any context.  But the ability to remember pitches in a context can help a lot for a singer to see sheet music and hear it in the right key.  Of course, this would work best for music they've seen/heard/sung/played the most, and would be less help for a new piece.  There is a reason they make pitch pipes.

Comment: As I'm sure the poster knows, ear training is valuable for musicians in general, not just vocalists.

Comment: @JeffLearman - Based on the question's "Can notated music be largely judged (by some) from the page, without literally hearing it?

EDIT - By judge I just meant the same way I would "judge" music upon listening.", I assumed that the question is aimed at evaluating new music, not evaluating sheet music of already familiar pieces.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I didn't mean to sound like I was contradicting you; sorry if I did.

Comment: When I trained at Juilliard (for classical singing), one of the very first things they teach you to do is to phonate (sound) the pitch "La" (solfege for the note A) without any outside reference. It wasn't easy and I can't say say I can do a perfect "La" today, but it sets you up for phonating all other pitches without any outside reference. After you get the La in your ear, you learn all of the intervals (m2, M2, m3, M3, etc...), so you can do the step in your head to the destination pitch, then sing it. It's call "relative pitch" finding (as opposed to "perfect pitch").

Comment: @InternetChordDatabase - Was that "La" fixed do or moveable do? If it was fixed do like you imply with "(solfege for the note A)", then I can't imagine people without absolute pitch getting the first note right even the majority of the time; if it was moveable do, then most versions of the exercise will sound different even given the same intervals, rhythms, dynamics, and timbres in the same order simply because no regard is given to making the initial "La" be the same note every time.

Comment: I can sight-read choral music, but I don't usually audiate just looking at sheet music. I know what to physically do to achieve various intervals, and I know where I'm supposed to be in the overall harmony, but I don't know what it sounds like until I've actually sung it.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Juilliard strictly uses the Fixed Do system. The idea with learning a "La" is you find the La within range (mine was A2 at 110 hz) and learn to hear it in your ear and phonate it without any auditory reference. I certainly didn't have perfect pitch when I learned have to do it, nor was it easy for me. But with practice, it took about 2 weeks to be able to do it 100% of the time. If I need to sing a C4 with no reference, I get my A2 in my head, I go up a m3 to C3, then up an octave to C4. Now I have C4 in my head and I'm ready to phonate it. It's not easy, but still a learnable skill

Comment: @InternetChordDatabase - Sounds like you already have absolute pitch to me. I started off similarly with absolute pitch in Grade 8, when I similarly could produce Middle C without reference 100% of the time and nothing else. I wonder how high the failure rate of that part of Juilliard's system is.

Comment: I think there are different kinds of "absolute pitch."  There are those who can, with little training or practice, identify any note (they only need to be taught the note names.)  At the other end of the spectrum, most musically trained people can learn one or two reference notes and use relative pitch from there.  Rick Beato on Youtube has a lot to say about it from various perspectives.

Answer (score 6):

With enough training and practice you can absolutely "hear" the music in your head as you read the sheet music.  And you can judge what it should sound like but that doesn't mean you can judge it as a performance.  Humans will inject some of their own "feeling" into it and that adds to the uniqueness of each rendition of the tune.  I've heard of classical guitarists who can learn a piece by reading it without hold in the guitar.  They can hear what it's supposed to sound like and can even feel it in the hand.  It still needs to be practiced and polished but it can be learnt by that method.

Answer (score 2):

The people most likely to be able to do this are composers and orchestral conductors. It is a mixture of inbuilt talent allied with plenty of practice.

You could argue that composers and conductors become good at this because they practise doing it. In my opinion, it is more likely the other way around. Because they can do it, they become composers and conductors!

---

Let's look first simply at the ability to *hear* music in one's head, quite apart from reading and writing it.

I'll speak for myself. I'm not blessed with the ability to do this at will but very often in a state between waking and sleeping, I can hear a full band/orchestra playing. I can pick out different instruments and even get them to play solos.

Here is a thread on the Young Composers website. It is clear from this that abilities to do this vary widely. https://www.youngcomposers.com/t30950/writing-music-in-your-head/ e.g.

> *Well, I write music in my head ALL the time. The thing is, in my head, the music never stops: See, it can be a piece of someone else's,
> a well known piece I'm thinking about, but about 50% of the time it's
> a piece of my own. When it is, I always think about some rhythms that
> I randomly tap out, then the melody, harmony, etc all come to me at
> the same time, all bunched in there. It's so natural for me, I never
> even thought about it being unusual. I mean, I also can get the idea
> anywhere, so I guess that's just me!*

Schumann apparently had exactly the same going on in his head.

> The Romantic composer Robert Schumann was said to have heard entire
> symphonies in his head from which he drew as inspiration for his
> music, but later in his life this phenomenon had diminished to just a
> note that played ceaselessly within his head.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_ear_syndrome

Nowadays, this is recognised as a mental (or perhaps rather brain) disorder that can be very distressing for some people.

> Musical hallucinations are a form of auditory hallucinations, in which
> patients hear songs, instrumental music or tunes, even though no such
> music is actually playing. Most patients realize they are
> hallucinating, and find the music intrusive and occasionally
> unpleasant. There is no cure.

> Musical ear syndrome (MES) describes a condition seen in people who
> have hearing loss and subsequently develop auditory hallucinations.
> "MES" has also been associated with musical hallucinations, which is a
> complex form of auditory hallucinations where an individual may
> experience music or sounds that are heard without an external
> source.[1] It is comparable to Charles Bonnet syndrome (visual
> hallucinations in visually impaired people) and some have suggested
> this phenomenon could be included under this diagnosis.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_ear_syndrome

> Musical hallucinations usually occur in older people. Several
> conditions are possible causes or predisposing factors, including
> hearing impairment, brain damage, epilepsy, intoxications and
> psychiatric disorders such as depression, schizophrenia and
> obsessive-compulsive disorder. Hearing impairment is the most common
> predisposing condition, but is not by itself sufficient to cause
> hallucinations.
> https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/08/130820094420.htm

---

Mozart had the ability from a young age to hear an entire piece of music at a concert, then go home and write it out as sheet music. He composed this way too. Sometimes he would be lazy and only write out the sheet music the night before a concert.

Here is a thread discussing the topic of hearing scores in one's head just by reading them. https://www.talkclassical.com/67924-those-you-who-can.html

**Answer**

The ability to hear a full orchestral score in one's head from reading the score is what makes a great orchestral conductor. The main job of such a conductor is the get real musicians to play what the conductor already hears in their head!

---

Edit

In response to a comment by @Internet Chord Database, I should make it clear that I don't intend to say that *only* conductors and composers have this ability. Other musicians do too. Also, for any kinds of musician, abilities will vary from being able hear a single part in your head, all the way up to imagining a whole orchestra.

Comment: I'd say singers are equally as likely to have this ability as composers and orchestral conductors. But I do agree that instrumentalists are less likely to have this skill.

Comment: @Internet Chord Database Good point. I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the skill of the musician and the complexity of the sheet music, but yes, musicians do totally hear in their heads the music they are reading and about to play. It is a skill that is learned, much the way that we learn to read text.

The skill comes in particularly useful when transposing at sight. It's often much easier to hear the music in your head as you read it and then play what you 'hear' in a different key, than it is to transpose by 'mechanically' working out the intervals from the printed dots. (I suspect this doesn't work if you have perfect pitch though!)

Answer (score 1):

Music is a language that can learnt (understood and spoken by almost everyone if it would be trained like our mother language. If you are taught by eartraining and sight reading  and you practice it everyday it becomes a part of you like a learnt foreign language. You start to think and combine motifs, chords, chord progressions and are able to right any rhythmic and melodic motif like you are able to sing it.

Of course there are individual differences of talents and flairs but we could all reach much more in this branch of capability if we were more interested and better trained from youth.

This assumption refers at least to the common practice music, but it can be extended by learning to the language of Wagner, Bruckner, Debussy and modern music. (All modern music has to be learnt like a new language, but this is possible, if you have been trained as a little child to speak one language and you have been trained in grammar and reading.)

Not all musicians need to train this ability, some just play their instrument without awareness of what they are doing. And as it is not necessary for their business they don't develop their capacity.